Within a space which is a 3-sphere, what the is surface area of a 2-sphere?
If an ant lives on a ball (2-sphere) with radius $r$, draws a circle and measures the radius of the circle as $R$ as it walks along the ball's curved area, it will find that the length of the circle is $U = 2\pi r \sin (R/r)$.
Question: raising all dimensions by one, what is the area of a 2-sphere if it lives in a 3-sphere? By raising all dimensions by one, I mean

space to live in: 2-sphere -> 3-sphere
geometrical object created: 1-sphere (circle) -> 2-sphere (ball)
length of circle $U$ -> area of 2-sphere $A$
measured radius of of the object created: $R$ in both cases
radius of space we live in: $r$ in both cases

What is $f$ in $A = f(R, r)$?

An $n$-sphere of radius $R$ in an $(n+1)$-spherical space of radius $r$ (with $R$ measured inside the spherical space and $r$ measured in $\Bbb R^{n+2}$ where the $(n+1)$-sphere is defined) is an $n$-sphere of radius $r\sin\frac Rr$ in a flat (i.e. Euclidean) $(n+1)$-dimensional cross section of $\Bbb R^{n+2}$. (This is easiest to visualize with $n=0$.) The surface measure is the same in both spaces (unlike the interior volume!), so we can plug $r\sin\frac Rr$ into the appropriate standard formula to compute it. For $n=2$ this gives $4\pi (r\sin\frac Rr)^2$.
